# Access: Saving on form with queried chart causes chart to no longer display

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

I have a chart (x-y scatterplot) that receives data from a query (x: date, y:some parameter). The user has access to various buttons and input fields that modify the query (change the parameter, date range, etc). If the user modifies the query to create a query that would return 0 results, the chart displays empty, as expected. When changing the query back, all returns to normal. However, if the user saves while the query is returning 0 results, then upon modifying the query, the chart does not repopulate.

The query does return data, and the form can still access it. The chart just will not display. When the chart is Locked and Disabled, simply exiting the form and opening is fixes this. When Unlocked and Enabled, this fix doesn't work (I have found that opening the chart and changing the data display to By Row and back to By Column fixes it in this case). Locked and Disabled is preferable to me anyway but the user should still not have to restart the form to fix this problem.

Additionally, while this problem occurs, the chart behaves as if it's empty: Cannot rename it, cannot change x/y boundaries, etc. I cannot change these properties of the chart because they do not exist, causing errors. What is going on here?

Comment: for clarification, the chart never disappears, it just appears empty.

Comment: I have experimented further into this and found that the SeriesCollection is absent when data is absent from the chart.  I have tried adding new series with MyGraph.SeriesCollection.NewSeries but this give me run time error 438. Still researching how to add a new series but having a hard time. It would be great if someone could help out